# how to convert string to datetime using sql in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

how to convert `string` to `datetime` using `sql` in `sqlite`?

In my sqlite db, the `puttime` column is `nvarchar` type, and store data as null, empty string, 2013-10-23, 2013-10-23 13:30:25, 2013-10-24 9:30:22

I use  the query below to convert , but the '2013-10-24 9:30:22' can't convert success, how to do it:

```
select puttime, datetime(puttime) from tb_news
```

result:

```
PutTime datetime(puttime)
2013-05-06          2013-05-06 00:00:00
2013-10-23          2013-10-23 00:00:00
2013-10-23 13:30:25 2013-10-23 13:30:25
2013-10-23 18:00:00 2013-10-23 18:00:00
2013-10-24 17:32:33 2013-10-24 17:32:33
2013-10-24 22:49:43 2013-10-24 22:49:43
2013-10-24 9:30:22  
2013-10-25 00:01:33 2013-10-25 00:01:33
```

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Closest date/time format SQLite expects is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Looking at your data, it seams that only deviation is `YYYY-MM-DD H:MM:SS`.

So, lets just add a `0` when needed:

```
SELECT puttime, DATETIME(
    CASE SUBSTR(puttime, 14, 1) WHEN ':' THEN puttime -- Found ':' after HH
    ELSE SUBSTR(puttime, 1, 11)||'0'||SUBSTR(puttime, 12) END
) FROM tb_news
```

Comment: thanks LS_dev, for data 2013-10-24 9:30:22, your answer is very correct. i'm sorry, i don't make the question clear, because the puttime column is nvarchar type, maybe this data will be other format , and datetime function can't  convert, for example: 2013-9-12 12:33:20, 2013-7-12, 2013-8-8 9:20:30, 2013-10-23 20:3:5, if i use the substr function more trouble, do you have a better solution do?

Comment: SQLite doesn't support any date/time type. Built-in functions support some specific formats. In your case, I would convert all existing dates to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` and get sure your applications store proper formatted strings. You may also create a trigger which correct inserted dates in database.

Answer (score -8):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(""dd-MM-yyyy");

SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

date = df2.format(format.parse(str));

try this one sir

Comment: These are not native functions to sqlite.